# React setstate not updating object array

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I am trying to update an object array but even though the correct values are passed to the function, the array remains blank.  If I try add a second object, then somehow the first one gets added and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
 const [qualifications, setQualifications] = useState([{}]);

  function handleAddQualification(values: any) {
    console.log(values);

    console.log(qualifications);

    setQualifications((prev) => {
      return [...prev, values];
    });

    console.log(qualifications);
  }
```

The values that I'm passing get logged correctly and the 2 subsequent logs of qualifications both show an empty array of objects.

I simplified the object so in my screen shot I added 'one' and the value logs correctly, but the qualifications array remains blank.   If I add a second entry of 'two' then for some reason it adds 'one' to the array.

Please share some insight as to what is going on here?

[image: adding 'one']

[image: adding 'two']

Comment: setState won't update immediately. what is the use case here? can you include some more code?

Comment: CAn you mention the final expected state here? Also, as Sarun mentioned, immediately logging after state change will not print correct values

Answer (score 1):

Here is example how event loop works :)

In your case:

1. Calling `handleAddQualification`
2. Log `values`, `qualifications`
3. Adding `setQualifications` to queue as async operation
4. Log `qualifications` again with the same result as from step 3
5. Here can works tasks from queue which was added before `setQualifications`
6. `setQualifications` updates `qualifications`

Take a look here for better understanding https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Answer (score 0):

The state update calls are asynchronous and you can't see them by logging just after update call.

1. The first object is empty because you have defined it in your default state and you update your new state using the previous state because of this the empty object always stays as first element in the array. To fix this set your `qualifications` to

```
interface Qual {
  subject?: string;
  level?: string;
  other?: string
}
```

```
const [qualifications, setQualifications] = useState<Qual[]>([]);
```

2. if you want to log state whenever it updates use an effect hook, something like this

```
useEffect(() => { 
    console.log({qualifications});
}, [qualifications])
```

Comment: If I initialize the array as empty, then I get a typescript error   'Argument of type '(prev: never[]) => any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
  Type '(prev: never[]) => any[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: never[]) => never[]'.
    Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.'

Comment: This fixed it!  Thanks again for your help.     const [qualifications, setQualifications] = useState<object[]>([]);

Comment: I have updated the code to suit your use case but you can change the interface as you like